# Android duplicate apk

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

When I build the project, two identical apks are generated:

[image]

The structure of the project as it is.

Can anyone say why it's happening, pls! ty

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you have another Activity with android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" in any of the manifest.xml files? Also check the manifest.xml in reader-nfc module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of add two intent-filter (category luncher)
need to remove this

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicate

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

From your `AndroidManifest`file. Check Both Module's `AndroidManifest` File